# How to handle authorship issues in an international multidisciplinary collaboration?

Tags: authorship, international

I am writing a paper that is co-authored by researchers at several national and international universities. The collaboration is also interdisciplinary, meaning that conventions for authorship vary a little regarding where to set the bar for inclusion/exclusion and how to order the names.

One of the co-authors would like to inflate the authorlist too much that I am comfortable with. There's several people I have never even met but who were involved in planning this big project some years ago.

I think we can discuss the situation just fine but I would like to find some material that I could use when arguing my views. What would be some good strategies here? Is there any guidelines for this kind of collaborations?

Answer (score 9):

Lots of folks around here seem to prefer [these](http://www.icmje.org/recommendations/browse/roles-and-responsibilities/defining-the-role-of-authors-and-contributors.html) guidelines which are known as the Vancouver Protocol (quoting directly, here):

- Substantial contributions to the conception or design of the work; or the acquisition, analysis, or interpretation of data for the work; AND
- Drafting the work or revising it critically for important intellectual content; AND
- Final approval of the version to be published; AND
- Agreement to be accountable for all aspects of the work in ensuring that questions related to the accuracy or integrity of any part of the work are appropriately investigated and resolved.

These are among the strongest criteria, and I would suggest that many scientific publications fail to live up to them. [Gift authorship](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3162772/) and other sorts of additions to the author list are common. E.g., maybe you include the PI of a large grant as last author even if they only lightly supervised the work and did not read the final draft or write or revise any of the actual words.

At another extreme, the LHC project has a sort of [communal authorship](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/Main/ATLASAuthorshipPolicy) process that led to to a recent paper with [more than 5000 authors](http://www.nature.com/news/physics-paper-sets-record-with-more-than-5-000-authors-1.17567). If you think this paper meets criteria 2 or 3 above, you are kidding yourself. Now, that whole community has agreed to this authorship mechanic, but it is substantially different from the Vancouver Protocol.

You need to ask yourself what the norms of your community are. Does your field have a professional society that has authorship guidelines or guidelines associated with its publications? If so, you can use those to bolster the arguments you want to make with your advisor. If not, you can look to other, similar areas and their approaches. In the end though, you may have to follow your advisor's lead until you are out on your own. This is not a hill for a grad student to die on, and postdocs and junior faculty may want to use caution.

Comment: In fact, I read about the Vancouver protocol for the first time here, and I'm sure that most of my colleagues never heard of it.

Comment: If you know where you aim to publish the paper you could also ask the specific journal for their authorship criteria (sometimes the "instructions for authors" page gives this information). I imagine the Vancouver Protocol is more or less standard (one journal I just checked links to the same page given in this answer), but it might be easier to convince reluctant co-authors to follow journal rules than recommendations from a committee. This could also clear up any disagreement with name ordering.

Comment: @ping That sounds like an answer, not just a comment. ;)

Answer (score 5):

As Bill Barth mentions, there are guidelines available for determining who should and shouldn't be an author.

However, if you know where you intend to submit the paper you can potentially use that journal's own specific rules as a more firm approach. The logic there is that if you are against stubborn people, they may be more convinced by hard rules from a journal than by a set of guidelines produced by a committee (which, while useful, are not really binding in any way).

This might be especially useful given that you are talking about interdisciplinary research where multiple fields could be involved with each having a different way of doing things. In that case, you can use the journal guidelines as the one that must be followed without having to argue for one field's values to be more respected than another's (although I don't know if the criteria for inclusion varies as much between disciplines as the ordering of authors does?)

It might be worth checking if the journal has a clear set of guidelines for authorship on it's website. For example, [author instructions for eLife](http://submit.elifesciences.org/html/elife_author_instructions.html) links to the set of instructions mentioned by Bill Barth.

The journal may also have their own guidelines for how author order should be decided (some fields go with alphabetical, while others take contribution and other things into account). However, from what I've seen, many guidelines here are unfortunately vague and tend to just say that all authors should agree on the order and should be able to explain how it was determined.